# how to delete or remove duplicated rows have the same data in dataGridView in c# desktop application

Tags: c#, datagridview

for ( int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

{
string removecelldub = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == removecelldub)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);
}
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: best approach is to address the problem in the source of the data, not in the ui control itself.  then re-bind the control to the fixed data source